# Can I connect a printer directly to a router via USB to Ethernet adapter?

Tags: usb, printer, ethernet, adapter, print-server

I need to connect an old printer to a router. The problem is that the printer is far away from the router and the only available output is USB. Near the printer I have an Ethernet port that is connected to the router.

My router supports the "sharing printers" feature. It works like a print server, right?

Is it possible to connect the printer to the Ethernet port with a Female USB to male Ethernet Adapter?

Comment: You can just connect the printer to a PC that is always on and then share it out and then point to it for printing as a shared printer as `\\<PCName>\<PrinterShareName>` this is a workaround to your issue that I've had to implement here and there in the past. As long as the PC and printer stays powered and connected to the network, it should work just fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No...
These USB-Ethernet connectors require an Operating System that handles the network connection on the device in which you plug the USB side.
That is the printer in your case, which doesn't have an operating system capable of handling this.

Answer (score 2):

What you suggested will not work.  What people usually do is use a Ethernet to USB printer server such as this example:  http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16833139009

Comment: If you want to use a USB printserver, make sure it supports your printer. Most USB-only printers are host-based and will ONLY work with printservers that specifically support it. Look up the "printer support list" for the printserver - all reputable manufacturers should be able to supply one. If your printer is not in the list, you must assume that it will NOT work.

Answer (score 1):

That will not work.  USB and Ethernet are not the same and you cannot convert one to the other directly.  You will need a USB to Ethernet converter, like [this](http://www.newegg.com/Product/ProductList.aspx?Description=usb%20to%20ethernet%20converter%20for%20printer&Submit=ENE).

Answer (score 0):

you can connect usb printer to router directly.no need to buy/purchase any additional hardware.watch this https://youtu.be/CHyuJIvwJPc